# Unable to upload docs > 37 MB through CMIS API

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, file-upload, cmis, large-file

My SharePoint 2013 version is 15.0.4569.1506. I am unable to upload a document greater than 37 MB in SharePoint through my below CMIS code. But directly into SharePoint I am able to do so. I have also tried increasing my heap size / cache limits.

I receive an exception like this:

> 'CmisRuntimeException : Found'

```
Folder someFolder = (Folder) session.getObjectByPath("/TestFolder");

File file = new File("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/50MBFile.zip"); 
String fileName = file.getName();

Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
props.put("cmis:objectTypeId", "cmis:document");
props.put("cmis:name",fileName);

String mimetype = "application/octet-stream";

ContentStream contentStream = session.getObjectFactory().createContentStream(fileName,
                file.length(),
                mimetype,
                new FileInputStream(file));

VersioningState versioningState = null;

Document someDoc = someFolder.createDocument(props, contentStream, versioningState );
```

I have used AtomPub Binding. Is something wrong in my code or any other SharePoint/CMIS setting I need to change ?

The code for Session Creation :

```
String atompub_url = "http://myserver/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/repository_id?getRepositoryInfo";
String username ="username";
String password = "password";

//put everything into a HashMap
Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String,String>();

parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER,username);
parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, password);
parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, atompub_url);
parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE,BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());

parameter.put(SessionParameter.COOKIES, "true")
parameter.put(SessionParameter.COMPRESSION, "true")
parameter.put(SessionParameter.CACHE_TTL_OBJECTS, "5000")
parameter.put(SessionParameter.CACHE_TTL_PATHTOID, "5000")

parameter.put(SessionParameter.AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDER_CLASS, CmisBindingFactory.NTLM_AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDER);
parameter.put(SessionParameter.REPOSITORY_ID, "F6497840-5DE3-464E-B8B3-45AF629823B1");

parameter.put(SessionParameter.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, "999999");
parameter.put(SessionParameter.READ_TIMEOUT, "999999");

SessionFactory factory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
Session session = factory.createSession(parameter);
```

Comment: Could you please also include the code that creates the session object, including the CMIS URL? (you can randomize the domain name). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved. I used Fiddler and found that I was exceeding the maximum request length allowed by SharePoint. I changed the value of maxRequestLength attribute in web.config files in SharePoint and able to now upload large files.